# Ionic: hide Android App Launcher?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

on android apps, when developing native Android app, one can hide it from launcher, so it only gets executed from intent of another app. With that I can hide the app icon on the home screen.

The way to do it in Android Native is:

remove this line from AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
```

add this line to AndroidManifesst.xml:

```
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
```

Is it posible to make the same thing using Ionic? 
How can I edit the built AndroidManifest?

Thanks!

Comment: In `platforms/android` there is an `AndroidManifest.xml` file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [edit-config](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config) provided by Cordova. This can edit/replace XML nodes in the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Here's an example how it should look for you:

```
<edit-config target="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application/activity[@android:name='MainActivity']/intent-filter/category" mode="overwrite">
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</edit-config>
```

`MainActivity` should be replaced by your activity's name, of course.
Also note that this should be in the `config.xml` file under the `<platform name="android">` node.